# How do I convert this hex or binary data back to the original Image?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a .sqlite file that has this blob data stored. I know the blob data is image but I don't know how to export it back to the original image.

[image]

Comment: Save it as a file?

Comment: already tried, it fails to open

Comment: What you posted shows an extra byte, `0x01` at the start of the binary data. A PNG file starts with `0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47`, not `0x01 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47`. How was that image *inserted*? Assuming there are no other errors, you can write everything after the first byte to disk

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't exactly know about how the image was inserted, I got this data from a client, it have thousands of image which I would need to download manually (by searching each one individually) if I'm unable to decode from it from this SQLite DB.

Comment: There's nothing to decode. The data has a bad extra byte at the start of the image. If you remove it, the image will probably wok. The [File header of a PNG file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header) can't start with `0x01`. The image you posted looks like what a PNG file should look like except that extra byte. You may be able to read the file by exporting the data *except* the first byte. How you do that depends on the language you use. You haven't posted the code you use for exporting by the way.

Comment: I was using flutter to decode the data, turned out the data was in 8 bit Unsigned Integer format, after removing the first bit it was easy to get an image using Image.memory(data)